# Is there a way to manipulate the timing between console.log output and the next userInput prompt using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am learning JS. I'm playing with a standard, easy-practice JS "game" like "Choose Your Own Adventure." I'm working with basic "if/else" statements and I want it to output:

'{Prompt/getUserInput} first -- Then {console.log}, THEN {prompt}, then {console.log}, etc.'

However, when I'm putting the code into repl.it, I'm getting {prompt}{prompt}{prompt} and then all the console logs. -- here is a snippet so you can see what I mean:

```
var buffer = function(){
console.log("------------------");
}
console.log("You are alone in the woods...");

buffer()
var userInput = prompt("You can either walk further into the woods or    turn around. Please enter 'go on' or 'screw this'");

if(userInput === "go on"){ 
console.log("It is getting darker and darker. By the time you hear his heavy breathing behind you, it is too late");
}

if (userInput === "screw this"){
console.log("You always knew you were the only person in the village with a lick of sense. Now, where did you hide those bodies...");
}

buffer();
```

Is there a way to have it read more A.B.A.B rather than AAA.BBB?

Comment: Where are you getting the AAA.BBB pattern? This code appears fine in Chrome.

Comment: I agree with hopkins-matt I just added more prompts and logs both inside and out of the initial if statments and I am getting the desired results. [Check out the fiddle I am using](https://jsfiddle.net/tmynpqhj/)

Comment: Yeah repl.it is messing it up, I think it is on their end.

Comment: I will add that you should use `.toUpperCase()` or `.toLowerCase()` on your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. There should be some bug with the repl.it implementation
If you open your console in your browser (for chrome is ctrl+shift+j | cmd+opt+j, for firefox ctrl+shift+k | cmd+opt+k) then paste your code and press enter it will work